# Contact merge is throwing "Could not find valid value for cid"

Tags: civimember, duplicate-contacts

We've recently started getting "Could not find valid value for cid" when trying to merge contacts. I just upgraded CiviCRM from 4.5.8 to 4.6.4 in the hopes it would cure the problem and it did not. This is a very big problem for us at the moment as we are approaching a convention and we *really* need to have accurate data for our members, but we have several duplicate contacts and memberships that can't be merged.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this are greatly appreciated.

Matt Nye Drupal 7.38/CiviCRM 4.6.4

Comment: If it used to work but doesn't now, a good place to start would be to try to identify what has changed. Some things to consider and add to your question either in the negative or positive include: Did you install an extension? You upgraded from 4.5.8. to 4.6.4 to try to fix the problem - did merging ever work for you on 4.5.8.  Have you had to restore from a back-up? ..

Comment: Is it a specific contact or with all of them?

Comment: Hi JoAnne - I believe it did work at some point under 4.5.8, but now that you say that I don't recall explicitly testing it after the upgrade. That isn't something I would normally think to test (although I'm adding it to the list, now, lol). I only recently discovered it had ceased working. I do not recall adding a particular extension that may have broken it. We're an all volunteer org, and the admin side of this site can go untouched for a month or two at a time.

Tom - I can't merge any contacts - same result for three I have tried so far.